# How to use FBSDKCoreKit to post image to users Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

So I am totally lost on how to post an image to a users timeline with the fbsdkcorekit. I was hoping it would be similar to twitter which I coded like so:

How can I share an image status like I did with twitter? I don't want to have the user have the dialog like it does with slcomposeviewcontroller. I just want it to happen in the background with a uiimage I provide as well as the status text that I provide.

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion {
let strUploadUrl = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"
        let strStatusUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        var twAPIClient = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
        var error: NSError?
        var parameters:Dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
        var imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.5)
        parameters["media"] = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        var twUploadRequest = twAPIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: strUploadUrl, parameters: parameters, error: &error)
        if true {
            println("before sendTwitterRequest")
            twAPIClient.sendTwitterRequest(twUploadRequest) {
                (uploadResponse, uploadResultData, uploadConnectionError) -> Void in
                println("inside sendTwitterRequest")
                if (uploadConnectionError == nil) {
                    // using SwiftyJSON to parse result
                    let json = JSON(data: uploadResultData!)
                    // check for media id in result
                    if (json["media_id_string"].string != nil) {
                        println("result = \(json)")
                        // post a status with link to media
                        parameters = Dictionary<String, String>()
                        parameters["status"] = ""
                        parameters["media_ids"] = json["media_id_string"].string!
                        var twStatusRequest = twAPIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: strStatusUrl, parameters: parameters, error: &error)
                        if true //(twStatusRequest != nil)
                        {
                            twAPIClient.sendTwitterRequest(twStatusRequest) { (statusResponse, statusData, statusConnectionError) -> Void in
                                if (statusConnectionError != nil) {
                                    println("Error posting status \(statusConnectionError)")
                                }
                            } // completion
                        } else {
                            println("Error creating status request \(error)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        println("Media_id not found in result = \(json)")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Error uploading image \(uploadConnectionError)")
                }
            } // completion
        } else {
            println("Error creating upload request \(error)")
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well documented in the "[Sharing on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)" section of the documentation.

Assuming you already completed [the basic setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) of installing the SDK and configuring your Xcode project, you should implement the [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) first and ask for the `publish_actions` permission (note: this permission requires prior review by Facebook before it can be used by non-app admins/developers/testers).

After you have implemented this, you can go to earlier mentioned "[Sharing on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)" guide for reference and use `[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];` to publish the content using the API directly instead of a dialog.